# Drawing circle and squares with radio buttons not working

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

my question today is to ask why when I switch radio buttons, drawing a circle and drawing a square don't work. This is for my paint program im creating. Please help me with this question. Also can you help why the program is so laggy? XD. The code is down here:

```js
var square = true

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myColor").value;
  ctx.fillStyle = x;
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var size = 5
var eraserSize = 5;
$('#colorForm input').on('change', function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = $(this).val();
});

$('#sizeForm input').on('change', function() {
  size = $(this).val();
});

function drawRect(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $("#canvas").offset().left - 4
  var posY = event.pageY - $("#canvas").offset().top - 4
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, size, size)
}

function drawCircle(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $("#canvas").offset().left
  var posY = event.pageY - $("#canvas").offset().top
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(posX, posY, size - 1, 0, Math.PI / 2, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function check() {
  if (square === true) {
    $("html").mousedown(function() {
      $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
        drawRect(event);
      })
      $("html").click(function(event) {
        drawRect(event);
      })
    })

    $("html").mouseup(function() {
      $("html").off("mousemove")
    })
  }
  if (square === false) {
    $("html").mousedown(function() {
      $("html").mousemove(function(event) {
        drawCircle(event);
      })
      $("html").click(function(event) {
        drawCircle(event);
      })
    })

    $("html").mouseup(function() {
      $("html").off("mousemove")
    })
  }
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?") == true) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800)
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  check();
}, 1)
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="cursor:crosshair"></canvas>
<br />
<STRONG>Choose your drawing shape</STRONG>:
<input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square = true" checked="checked">Square
<input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square = false">Circle
<br />
<STRONG>Color Settings</STRONG>:
<input type="color" id="myColor">
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
<br />Basic Colours:
<br />
<form id="colorForm">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" checked="checked">Black
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange">Orange
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow">Yellow
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">Green
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">Blue
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple">Purple
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="white">Eraser (White)
</form>
<form id="sizeForm">
  <br />
  <STRONG>Size</STRONG>:
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="10">Big
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="5" checked="checked">Normal
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="2">Small
</form>
<br />
<button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear Drawing</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.arc()` takes radians - 2π is a full circle, you are doing π/2 which is 90 degrees.  Here's an easy converter: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/radians-to-degrees.htm.

I adjusted your code below, you were not cleaning up the `onmousedown` listener.  The `click` listener is actually unnecessary, if a `mouseup` is used instead (since you're already `mousedown`, you have half of the click already).  The `setInterval` was unnecessary; you can listen for `mousedown` to start drawing.  Limiting the scope of the listeners to the canvas vs. all of the HTML can improve performance also.

```js
var square = true; // Set

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var size = 5
var eraserSize = 5;

$('#colorForm input, #myColor').on('change', function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = $(this).val();
});

$('#sizeForm input').on('change', function() {
  size = $(this).val();
});


function drawRect(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left - 4
  var posY = event.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top - 4
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, size, size)
}

function drawCircle(event) {
  var posX = event.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left
  var posY = event.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(posX, posY, size - 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  // We only care about mousemove on the canvas, not the whole page
  if (square) {
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', drawRect).on('mouseup', drawRect);
  } else {
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', drawCircle).on('mouseup', drawCircle);
  }

  // If the user mouseup outside of the canvas, we don't want to keep listening, so listen for mouseup on the whole page to remove our other drawing listeners
  $('html').one('mouseup', function() { // "one" means that it will only fire once and will stop listening after that (cleanup for free)
    $(canvas).off('mousemove').off('mouseup');
  });
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?") == true) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800)
  }
}

// We only care about mousedown on the canvas, not the whole page
$(canvas).on('mousedown', mouseDown);
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>

<h2>Choose your drawing shape:</h2>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square=true;" checked="checked">Square
  <input type="radio" name="shape" onclick="square=false;">Circle
</p>

<h2>Color Settings:</h2>

<input type="color" id="myColor" />

<form id="colorForm">
  <h3>Basic Colours:</h3>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" checked="checked" />Black
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange" />Orange
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" />Yellow
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />Blue
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple" />Purple
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="white" />Eraser (White)
  </p>
</form>


<form id="sizeForm">
  <h2>Size:</h2>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="10" />Big
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="5" checked="checked" />Normal
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="2" />Small
  </p>
</form>

<br />
<button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear Drawing</button>
```

Comment: No but when i want to draw the circle, both and square and the circle are being drawn how do you fix that? Also, why is the program laggy?

Comment: also it still is a bit not "laggy", but drawing is slow

Comment: The event tracking is firing slowly - this is a limitation of your browser/OS/hardware.  To "smooth" it out, oftentimes people will keep track of the previous point dropped, then draw a line to the current point.

However, the scope of this question has changed significantly and has broaded way too much.  Please open up a new question if you have something specific you'd like addressed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is missing a ton of semi-colons at the end of lines, which is VERY bad practice in general. I'd say your first line of action is to fill those in to make sure missing semi-colons is causing the issue.

Second, when you are changing the square variable, it is first assigning the *onmousedown* handler to use the *drawRect* method. However, when you select circle and square becomes false, you are then assigning the *onmousedown* handler to use the *drawCircle* method without unbinding the previous *onmousedown* handler. With jQuery, assigning a handler again does not overwrite the previous handler.

Another issue I see with this is that the circle is not being drawn correctly in the first place. If you set *square*=*false* initially and try to draw a circle, it is only drawing a semi-circle, so check your drawCircle.